# changing the value of Mainactivity variable in another class

Tags: java, android, string, android-activity, scope

I don't want to make a change in the copy, instead what I require is to make a change as a reference in the variable, so that the change should be reflected in the `mainactivity` class.

In my app, I have a global variable "key"  declared as public static in the `mainactivity` class, I have made a button "Reset key", which make an Intent to the other activity.

In that activity, I want to change the main activity's key value. what I m using is `String key1=MainActivity.key`
, and after that, I m making a change in the key1 variable, but after changing the variable hen I return to the main activity, the key variable is still same.

So, I want to make the change as a reference, not as a copy of the object or variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a static property:

```
private static String key1;
public void setKey(String newKey){
     key1 = newKey;
}
```

In the another activity call:

```
MainActivity.setKey(NewKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

First change the value of key1 and then assign this value to **MainActivity** **Key** variable like this.

```
MainActivity.key = key1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For OnClickListener it wouldn't work.I already faced that issue and for solution I had to use a method where I can change MainActivity variable value.

If you worked under OnClickListener then can follow below steps as I did.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static String mode = "Easy";
public static int dimension = 3;

......

}


public class SelectLevel extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_level);

    Button easy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    Button medium = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio1);

    easy.setOnClickListener(respondClick);
    medium.setOnClickListener(respondClick);
}

public OnClickListener respondClick = new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View MainActivity) {
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text;
        switch (MainActivity.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio0:
                text = "StartGame Pressed";
                /*MainActivity.dimension=3;
                MainActivity.mode="Easy";*/     //it will not work
                changeMainActivityVariable(3, "Easy");      // it's working fine
                break;
            case R.id.radio1:
                text = "StartGame Pressed";
                changeMainActivityVariable(4, "Medium");
                break;
            default:
                changeMainActivityVariable(3, "Easy");

        }


    }
};

public void changeMainActivityVariable(int dimension, String mode) {
    MainActivity.dimension = dimension;
    MainActivity.mode = mode;
}


}
```